# How to call method within another method using Java

Tags: java, methods

I've created a method that tests to see whether a number is a factor of another number.

```
    private static boolean isFactor( int n, int d )
    {
        if (n % d == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Now I have been instructed to call this method, "isFactor", in another method I've created like so:

```
    private static void printFactors( int n )
    {
        int divisor = 1;
        while (divisor <= n)
        {
            isFactor(n, divisor);
            if (isFactor == true)
                divisor++;
            else
                System.out.println("No factors found.");
            System.out.println("The factors of " + n + " are: " + divisor );
        }
   }
```

The problem is that I receive an error message during runtime saying that java cannot find symbol.  How do I make it so that my method can find it's counterpart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem is that I receive an error message during runtime saying that java cannot find symbol

Yes, this is noted in this line:

```
if (isFactor == true)
```

Because there's no `isFactor` variable. Instead, you should call the method in that line:

```
//isFactor(n, divisor);
if (isFactor(n, divisor)) //no need to put == true
```

Note: while statement above make your code compilable, it will not make it work as expected. You should separate the *divisor* and *quantity of divisors* of the number in different variables. Also, you should only print the message *No factors found.* if and only if you have found that the number has no divisors at all, not on every time you test the divisor.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I'll accept the answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me!

Comment: @WeekzGod make sure to read the bottom paragraph of the post.

Answer (score 1):

You've used the symbol `isFactor` as both a method name and a variable name.  Try this:

```
boolean result = isFactor(n, divisor);
if (result) { // No need to compare to true since it is boolean
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to resolve these type of problems in the future is to look at the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    isFactor cannot be resolved to a variable

    at stack.Main.printFactors(Main.java:24)
    at stack.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

This tells me the problem is at line 24 (which was called by line 7):

```
ln 7:      printFactors(100);
...
ln 18:     private static void printFactors( int n )
...
ln 24:     if (isFactor == true)
```

Additionally any decent IDE (ex: Eclipse) will allow you to find these type of Syntax errors without having to run your program.

[image]

Comment: I've never hear of it. Thanks. I'll look into it!.